# can i export|copy multiple postgresql queries into one csv file?

Tags: perl, postgresql

Is it possible to copy multiple postgresql queries into single csv file?
As of now am copying single query into csv file as

```
copy (select * from table1) to 'file.csv' with csv header;
```

Now i want to copy 2 query result together . Is that possible ? something like,

```
copy (select * from table1,select name from table2) to 'file.csv' with csv header
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You can:

```
copy (select 'table1' as table_id, * from table1
      UNION ALL
      select 'table2' as table_id, * from table2)
 to 'file.csv' with csv header
```

If tables have identical structure.

Or you can:

```
copy (select field1, field2, null, null from table1
      UNION ALL
      select null,null, field3, field4 from table2)
 to 'file.csv' with csv header
```

If tables don't have identical structure.

The problem is - `COPY ... FROM` can only work with tables (details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)).

So you will need to: `CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_copy_tbl`, `COPY tmp_copy_tbl FROM` and then `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM tmp_copy_tbl`